# Buoyancy, mechanic of fluids hydrostatics

Tags: fluid-statics, buoyancy

I am struggling to understand how to solve buoyancy problems, and I have one that would help clarify my mind if you could help me, please. There is a tank with depth H and a plug at the bottom of the tank attached with a string to a float at the top of the tank, which is semi-submerged at a height h. I have the densities of the objects, and I need to find the value of h at which the float is submerged. I know that I need to use Newton's first law to solve this, but the question concerns the plug. If there is no water beneath it, does it experience a buoyancy force? Buoyancy occurs because of the difference in pressures, and from that difference between forces, one acts downward and the other upward due to the larger pressure. However, in this case, there is no upward force because there is no pressure. Additionally, I don't know if the plug experiences a normal force. This leaves me with one equation and two variables, h and N, the normal force. I think there may not be a normal force, but I cannot explain why. https://ibb.co/v15qFv6

On an unrelated note, if I have an object at the bottom of a tank, and the tank is filled with two different fluids, how do I use Archimedes' principle in this case?

Comment: Usually in these circumstances your tank is open to the atmosphere at the top and the outside of the plug is too. The force on the plug is from atmospheric pressure. This is balanced by the atmospheric pressure at the free surface of in the tank. The whole thing is simplified by taking the free surface to be at 0 (gauge) rather than atmospheric (absolute) and ignoring the atmosphere on the plug too. Is this how the problem is set up?

Comment: Additionally, what is the length of the string? What are the dimensions of the float?

Comment: https://ibb.co/v15qFv6
This is a photo of the problem.

Comment: OK, so there must be information about the fluid and the float. The fluid is probably water. What is the float made of? Are you supposed to find when the float submerges or when the plug opens up?

Comment: I stated that I have the densities of both plug and float , I need to find the value h which is the depth that the float is submerged. My problem was with the normal force if there is one and the buoyancy of the plug which again if there is a buoyancy force or just pressure downward acting on it.  * hf in the photo

Comment: The plug has the force of the water pressure acting down on it and the tension of the plug line pulling up. If you use gauge pressure for the water, you can ignore the external atmospheric pressure pushing up on the plug.

Comment: Why doesn’t it feel normal force ? From the bottom of the tank.

Comment: I'm sorry, but to me the word "plug" means it is plugging a hole to the outside. Something sitting on the bottom of the tank might be a "weight" or something like that. Is the triangle supposed to be plugging a hole or sitting on the bottom?

Comment: According to the question it’s plugging a hole. You say that if it was just a weight lie there , then it would feel normal force ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143163/discussion-between-lourdes-and-poisson-aerohead).